# React retrieve checked value in checkbox

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to retrieve the checked values of the checkboxes and save them into array.
I tried :

```
arr.push(setNewItem(checked))
arr.push(e.target.value.checked)
arr.push(items.checked)
```

But these return type error or undefined values.

```
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([]);
const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      var arr = [...checkedItems];
      //arr.push(setNewItem(e.target.value.checked));
      setCheckedItems(arr);
      console.log(arr);
    } else {
      checkedItems = "";
    }
    setIsChecked((current) => !current);
  };
```

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyleForm>
        <StyleInput
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add"
          value={newItem}
          onChange={(e) => setNewItem(e.target.value)}
          onKeyPress={handleOnKeyPress}
        />
        <ButtonAddStyle onClick={() => addItem()}>add</ButtonAddStyle>

        <StyleUl>
          {items.map((item) => {
            return (
              <StyleLi key={item.id}>
                <StyleCheckBox
                  type="checkbox"
                  value={isChecked}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                {item.value}
                {""}
                <ButtonDelStyle onClick={() => deleteItem(item.id)}>
                  X
                </ButtonDelStyle>
              </StyleLi>
            );
          })}
        </StyleUl>
      </StyleForm>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.push(e.target.checked);
```

Is the way to go and get rif of :

```
else {
checkedItems = "";
}
```

you cannot update a state this way, you will get an error when you try to unchek an input:

> Uncaught TypeError : Assignment to constant variable

Now let's see what you are trying to do you are storing `e.target.checked` each time an input is cheked so `checkedItems` will look something like this :

```
[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

why do you need this ? better is to store the ids of checked items :

```
const handleChange = (isChecked, id) => {
  var arr = [...checkedItems];
  if (isChecked) {
    arr.push(id);
    setCheckedItems(arr);
  } else {
    setCheckedItems(checkedItems.filter((storedId) => storedId !== id)); // delete the id from checkedItems if the corresponding input is unckecked
  }
};
```

and from jsx :

```
<StyleCheckBox
  type="checkbox"
  value={item.id}
  onChange={(e) => {
    handleChange(e.target.checked, item.id);
  }}
/>;
```

Now look at this :

```
<StyleCheckBox
  value={isChecked} // this line
>
```

you are mapping through `items` creating multiple checkBoxes but all of them share the same value. and the value attribute of an input of type checkbox is not what you think it is, learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value). so you can use `value={item.id}` to have an unique value for each input and get rid of `isChecked` useState hook you really don't need it

Answer (score 0):

this could solve your problem.

```
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = useState([]);
const handleChange = (e) => {
  setCheckedItems( prev => [...prev, e.target.checked]);
  setIsChecked((current) => !current);
};
```